# How to send an array of JSON object as a parameter value in request body ios swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, api, http-post

Hello I'm using Invoice generator api JSON Input
https://invoice-generator.com/developers#json-input
In the documentation of the API it is mentioned that the items key takes an array of json objects as value. [image]

Here is my swift dictionary representation of the body

```
let parameters: [String: Any] = [
        "from":"Invoiced, Inc.",
        "to": "Acme, Corp.",
        "logo":"https://invoiced.com/img/logo-invoice.png",
        "number":1,
        "items":["name":"starter plan",
                 "quantity":1,
                "unit_cost":99],
        "notes":"Thanks for your business!"
    ]
```

The problem is I get my invoice and display it in PDFView when I send an empty item array as

```
item:[]
```

But when I send with some values in the array I get invalid response from the server.

How can I send an array of JSON objects as a  value for item key in the API request body

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlrequest/2011522-addvalue

Comment: Your body is wrong, it should be `items":[[...]]` (with one `[]` for an array, and the other one for the element inside the array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode an object to JSON. First, you should create the object:

```
struct JSONParameters {
    let from: String
    let to: String
    let logo: String
    let number: Int
    // ... all other parameters
}
```

Then, encode it to JSON and add it to the request body:

```
            do {
                let parameters = JSONParameters(from: "Invoiced Inc.", to:......)   // Complete object
                let json = try JSONEncoder().encode(parameters)
                print("Encoded JSON: \(String(data: json, encoding: .utf8)!)")

                var request = URLRequest(url: yourURLHere)
                request.httpBody = json

                let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request) // Or whatever function you need to use

                // Manage response

            } catch {
                print("\n-->> Error trying to encode : \(error) - \(String(describing: parameters))")
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

**OUTPUT: -**

> ```
> [
>     "number": 1,
>     "to": "Acme, Corp.",
>     "notes": "Thanks for your business!",
>     "from": "Invoiced, Inc.",
>     "logo": "https://invoiced.com/img/logo-invoice.png",
>     "items": [
>         ["quantity": 1, "name": "Starter plan", "unit_cost": 99],
>         ["quantity": 1, "name": "Starter plan2", "unit_cost": 99]
>     ]
> ]
> ```

> ```
> struct BodyModel: Codable {
>     var from, to: String?
>     var logo: String?
>     var number: Int?
>     var items: [Item]?
>     var notes: String?
>     
>     func toDict() -> [String:Any] {
>         var dictionary = [String:Any]()
>         if from != nil {
>             dictionary["from"] = from
>         }
>         if to != nil {
>             dictionary["to"] = to
>         }
>         if logo != nil {
>             dictionary["logo"] = logo
>         }
>         if number != nil {
>             dictionary["number"] = number
>         }
>         if items != nil {
>             var arrOfDict = [[String:Any]]()
>             for item in items! {
>                 arrOfDict.append(item.toDict())
>             }
>             dictionary["items"] = arrOfDict
>         }
>         if notes != nil {
>             dictionary["notes"] = notes
>         }
>         return dictionary
>     }
> }
> ```

> ```
> struct Item: Codable {
>     var name: String?
>     var quantity, unit_cost: Int?
>     
>     func toDict() -> [String:Any] {
>         var dictionary = [String:Any]()
>         if name != nil {
>             dictionary["name"] = name
>         }
>         if quantity != nil {
>             dictionary["quantity"] = quantity
>         }
>         if unit_cost != nil {
>             dictionary["unit_cost"] = unit_cost
>         }
>         return dictionary
>     }
> }
> ```

> ```
> class ViewController: UIViewController {
>
>     override func viewDidLoad() {
>         super.viewDidLoad()
>         
>         var arrItems = [Item]()
>         arrItems.append(Item(name: "Starter plan", quantity: 1, unit_cost: 99))
>         arrItems.append(Item(name: "Starter plan2", quantity: 1, unit_cost: 99))
>         
>         let body = BodyModel(from: "Invoiced, Inc.",
>                              to: "Acme, Corp.",
>                              logo: "https://invoiced.com/img/logo-invoice.png",
>                              number: 1,
>                              items: arrItems,
>                              notes: "Thanks for your business!")
>         
>         let parameters: [String: Any]  = body.toDict()
>         print(parameters)
>         
>     }
> }
> ```

[image]